# SQL Text Matching

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I would like to find a pattern of 3-2 numbers followed by an X and 3-2 numbers. In other programs I would use REGEX, how can this be done in SQL?

Example:

**Input**

```
NH_90x873_nyc_hi
Spring_Summer_908x780_Sam
Fall_Winter_pluto_890x80_Mike_LA_Earth
```

**Output**

```
90x873
908x780
890x80
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it always 3-2 digits?

Comment: yes always 2-3 on either end

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select regexp_substr('[0-9]+x[0-9]+','NH_960x867_nyc_hi')
```

If you want to limit the number of digits to only 2-3

```
select regexp_substr('[0-9]{2,3}x[0-9]{2,3}','NH_960x867_nyc_hi')
```

Comment: unfortunately, the regexp_substr function does not work

Comment: @sergiospizzirri You tagged amazon-redshift so I assumed it would and should. What string functions are available to you?